# Inkscape crashes - internal error at select font

Tags: inkscape

Start inkscape

Click menu text --> font & text to open text dialog

Click text tool (F8)

Click drop down field in tool control bar

Inkscape crashes.

How do I bypass or solve this?

Comment: This isn't a user question, but a bug report and should be reported on their bugtracker/at their site.

Comment: You may want to include your platform and Inkscape versions for completeness. I'd suggest [you file a bug report](https://inkscape.org/en/contribute/report-bugs/) to the Inkscape developers.

Comment: Being Inkscape an open-source tool then all we users should raise bugs when we find them, in order to help the developers. This questions looks much like a bug report. 
In order to get answers here you might want to ask for a way to circumvent the issue, always stating that you checked that the bug is raised,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By-pass,

Don't click on the dropdown, instead click inside the dropdown and delete the name of the current font, and write the name of the font you need.